# How to build a GET request from a CSW POST request

Tags: query, spatial-query, csw, post

For accessing some data in a GeoNetwork metadata catalogue using CSW, I would need the URL for a GET request that would include also a geospatial filter (bounding box) and a time of interest (start time and end time) like:

```
> http://my_IP/geonetwork/srv/ita/csw?Request=GetRecords&service=CSW&resultType=results&version=2.0.2&typeNames=csw:Record&ElementSetName=full&CONSTRAINTLANGUAGE=CQL_TEXT&constraint_language_version=1.1.0&maxrecords=150&`
```

How to complete it to include spatial and temporal filters?

I searched for material online but I could not find any useful reference. I have the general POST request but I need the one with GET method for a specific purpose.

Comment: So, what does the POST request look like?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, to find out what is possible in a specification in this case CSW, the starting point is the specification documentation.  OGC Catalogue Service specifications are listed at:

https://www.ogc.org/standards/cat

and for `version=2.0.2&` as per your GET request example you'd want:

http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=20555

You'd also want to look at the Filter Encoding specifications:

https://www.ogc.org/standards/filter

For what is possible/enabled in any individual service you need to look at the information in the GetCapabilities response, which for your example would be:

```
http://my_IP/geonetwork/srv/ita/csw?Request=GetCapabilities&service=CSW&version=2.0.2&
```